# JQuery- remove and add back certain options in a select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this select that is constantly changing (adding, removing, etc)...

It goes something like this:

```
<select class="validation" id="6401e0f3802aa3c1d76feca811b3c43c" name="attribute[75]">
<option value="109">Leather 1000</option>
<option value="111">Leather 2000 (+$300.00)</option>
<option value="112">Leather 3000 (+$400.00)</option>
<option value="113">Leather 5000 (+$500.00)</option>
</select>
```

I am using jQuery to strip out all the color options, which looks like this:

```
<select class="validation" id="" name="attribute[76]">
<option value="210">1000-Black</option>
<option value="211">2000-Black</option>
<option value="212">3000-Black</option>
<option value="213">5000-Black</option>
</select>
```

The number before the color corresponds with the leather type.  My problem is that there are several hundred color options per leather type.

I am currently using this plugin:

```
(function($){

$.fn.extend({detachOptions: function(o) {
    var s = this;
    return s.each(function(){
        var d = s.data('selectOptions') || [];
        s.find(o).each(function() {
            d.push($(this).detach());
        });
        s.data('selectOptions', d);
    });
}, attachOptions: function(o) {
    var s = this;
    return s.each(function(){
        var d = s.data('selectOptions') || [];
        for (var i in d) {
            if (d[i].is(o)) {
                s.append(d[i]);
                console.log(d[i]);
                // TODO: remove option from data array
            }
        }
    });
}});   

})(jQuery);
```

To strip out all other options, including the colors.  Currently I have fabric choices and colors working ok, but I need to remove and add only certain colors, and I need it to work automatically.

What I need to do is when Leather 1000 is selected, I need ONLY the color options that have 1000- in it.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/8x7Cz/

be aware of the `// tricky part` you might want to change this

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector for your needs. Here's some very rough code to get your started.

```
$('select[name="attribute[76]"] option:contains("1000")')
```